# Is Memcached for me?

Tags: memcached

I am SysAdmin for a couple of large online shops and I'm researching Memcached as a possible caching solution.

The most accessed queries are the ones which make up the dynamic product pages, so it would make sense to cache these.  Staff regularly use an update program to update the tables with new prices.  As I understand, if I used Memcached the changes would only be apparent after the cache expires and not after my program has updated.

In the docs, I can see "Memcache::flush" which flushes ALL existing items, but is there a way to flush an individual object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in [docs](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommands) that there is [delete](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommands#delete) command that removes one item. Also there is a [set](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommands#set) to add or replace one item.

Answer (score 0):

The most important part is to have a solid naming scheme on your keys.  Presumably you have a cms type page to update/insert rows in your database (mysql?).  Just ensure that you delete the memcache record whenever you do an update in mysql and you'll be fine.